# Getting this error while creating signed apk

Tags: android

Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

my build.gradle(app) file is:

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   android {
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "newsall1.shiva.newsall1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.0.2'
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

Comment: You need to post the error that you're getting, we won't be able to identify it from your build.gradle file... It would be best if you could paste the logs with the details. If you are having trouble finding them, go to the Terminal window in Android Studio and run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and paste the output here.

Comment: I already gave you the error name,Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:

Comment: That's the high level error, you need to check the logs for details (low level error, actually tells you what went wrong). Just run "gradlew assembleDebug" in the project's directory and post the output here.

Answer (score 6):

```
android {
....
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
.....}
```

Adding the above two lines ,generated the signed APK and removed the AAPT2 error while building release APK.

Answer (score 0):

go to build option from menu in android studio and select clean project it might resolve the issue